# Issue loading objects from model in Django

Tags: python, django

I am currently writing a web application in Django for an interview.

On the home page I am looking to have 3 lists of various data.

This is the error I receive when loading the home page:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Critical'
```

This is the models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Status(models.Model):
    status_level=models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status_level


class Event(models.Model):
    event_status=models.ForeignKey(Status)
    event_title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    event_description=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    event_flag=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    date_active=models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    time_active=models.TimeField(default=timezone.now())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_title
```

There are 3 status objects currently, Critical, Medium and Low.

Views.py:

```
def index(request):
    # home page
    critical_list=Event.objects.filter(event_status='Critical')
    medium_list=Event.objects.filter(event_status='Medium')
    low_list=Event.objects.filter(event_status='Low')

    context_dict={'critical':critical_list, 'medium':medium_list,'low':low_list}
    return render(request, 'server_status/index.html',context_dict)
```

There's a lot of stacktrace so I shall post the two relevant lines which I believe are causing the problem:

The error occurs at this line:

```
critical_list=Event.objects.filter(event_status='Critical')
```

And then the last line on the stacktrace:

```
   return int(value) ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
self    
<django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>
value   
'Critical'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you appear to be trying to filter on the status_level on the Status model

```
critical_list=Event.objects.filter(event_status__status_level='Critical')
```

Comment: You are most welcome. Since you are still new here, may i point out that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation).

Comment: Thanks, I've never noticed the accept answer button before you pointed it out!

Comment: you can accept your own answer too, like in the first question you had posted here